# How to mix Android JUnit classes with plain JUnit classes in same project

Tags: android, junit

Is it possible to have both Android JUnit classes (i.e. extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<>`) with plain JUnit classes (i.e. extends `TestCase`)  in the same project?

Some of the classes in my app are "generic" (i.e. do not require an activity or the emulator to be tested) and I would like to created test cases for them, but without having to create a separate test **project**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. There should be no problem in having different super classes in the same test project.

Answer (score 0):

See this http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/junit-test-example.html

This is the best tutorial I have found on the subject.